# The $n$ th derivative of $\ln(xy)/(1-xy)$ with respect to $x$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, closed-form

I'm looking for a closed form of

\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left( \frac{\ln(xy)}{1-xy} \right) 
\end{align}

I tried using the Taylor series:
\begin{align}
 \frac{\ln(xy)}{1-xy}   =  \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} (1-xy)^{k}} {1-xy} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} (1-xy)^{k-1}
\end{align}

I think there is a wrong sign above. I'm not sure how to proceed and if this is useful for a closed form.

Comment: $\left( \frac{\ln(xy)}{1-xy} \right)^{n}$ is the $n$-th power. The title talks about the $n$-th derivative (with respect to $x$).

Comment: $n-$th derivative is usually denoted by $(n),$ with brackets.

Comment: Your approach can be useful. Compare your result with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor(log(xy),x)

Comment: By rescaling the variable $x$, you can pull $y$ out of the expression.

Comment: Is $y$ an independent variable, or is it to be understood as a function of $x$, i.e., $y=y(x)$?

Comment: Maybe this is considered a closed form without summation by the OP.  For complex numbers $x,y\neq 0$, we have $$\frac{{\partial}^n}{\partial x^n}\,\frac{\ln(xy)}{1-xy}=\frac{n!}{2\pi\text{i}}\,\oint_{\partial B\left(x,\min\left\{\frac{|x|}{2},\frac{1}{2|y|}\right\}^{\vphantom{a^{a^a}}}_{\vphantom{a_{a_a}}}\right)}\,\frac{\ln(zy)}{(1-zy)\,(z-x)^{n+1}}\,\text{d}z\,,$$ where $$B(w,r):=\big\{w\in\mathbb{C}\,\big|\,|w|<r\big\}$$ is the ball of radius $r>0$ centered at $w\in\mathbb{C}$, and $$\partial B(w,r):=\big\{w\in\mathbb{C}\,\big|\,|w|=r\big\}$$ is the boundary of $B(w,r)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $y$ is treated as a constant parameter here.  Let $z=xy$.  Then, the required expression is
$$E=y^n\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\frac{\ln z }{1-z}.$$
We have by the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) that
$$\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\frac{\ln z }{1-z}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{d^k}{dz^k}\ln z\right)\left(\frac{d^{n-k}}{dz^{n-k}}\frac{1}{1-z}\right).$$
Thus,
$$E=y^n\Biggl(\frac{n!\ln z}{(1-z)^{n+1}}+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!}{z^k}\left(\frac{(n-k)!}{(1-z)^{n-k+1}}\right)\Biggr).$$
Plugging in $z=xy$, we get
$$E=n!y^n\left(\frac{\ln(xy)}{(1-xy)^{n+1}}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k(xy)^k(1-xy)^{n-k+1}}\right).$$
You can also write
$$E=\frac{n!}{1-xy}\left(\frac{y^n\ln(xy)}{(1-xy)^{n}}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-1}y^{n-k}}{kx^k(1-xy)^{n-k}}\right).$$

Comment: I'm looking for something that doesn't require a sum ($\sum$).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a trully an answer.With CAS:

$$\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial x^n}\frac{\ln (x y)}{1-x y}=\\-\frac{(-x)^{-n} n! \, _2F_1\left(1,1+n;2+n;1-\frac{1}{x y}\right)}{(1+n) x y}+(-x)^{-n} (-x
   y)^n (1-x y)^{-1-n} n! \ln \left(\frac{1}{x y}\right)+y^n (1-x y)^{-1-n} n! \ln (x y)$$

Mathematica code:

```
 D[Log[x y]/(1 - x y), {x, n}] ==
 -(((-x)^-n n! Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + n, 2 + n, 1 - 1/(x y)])/((1 + n) x y)) + (-x)^-n (-x y)^n (1 - x y)^(-1 - n) n! Log[1/(x y)] + y^n (1 - x y)^(-1 - n) n! Log[x y]]
```

Comment: There the OP has it.  This answer no longer contains a summation, but an ominous hypergeometric function.